# DataRow get values of duplicate column of join table in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I have following query

```
string query = string.Format("select * from `{0}` inner join `{1}` on `{0}`.Id = `{1}`.RecordId where recordid= {2}", tableName, GetAuditTableName(tableName), context.RecordId);
```

I am executing this query by following way:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();
DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   dtRecords.Load(reader);
}
conn.Close();
List<AuditLog> records = new List<AuditLog>();
foreach (DataRow row in dtRecords.Rows)
{
records.Add(new AuditLog
{
    CreatedOn = row["CreatedOn"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(row["CreatedOn"].ToString()) : DateTime.MinValue,
});
}
```

So here I am fetching the record one by one by using `DataRow`. But my issue is there are two same column i.e. `CreatedOn` in both table. Here I want to select `CreatedOn` column value from `Join` table and other column value from first table. How can I select this value?

Comment: set another alias for CreatedOn column from 2nd table. or acces dataRow values by column index (e.g. row[0])

Comment: is there any way where I can Select value some thing like `row["table2.CreatedOn"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query and use alias for column in join table. Like:

```
select table1.*, table2.CreatedOn as CreatedOn2 from `{0}` as table1 inner join `{1}` as table2 on table1.Id = table2.RecordId where table2.recordid= {2}
```

And select `CreatedOn2` field,

```
CreatedOn = row["CreatedOn2"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(row["CreatedOn2"].ToString()) : DateTime.MinValue
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I don't want to add `table2.CreatedOn as CreatedOn2`. Because I have lots of column to select. So I don't want to select each of these. That's why I used `*`

Comment: is there any way where I can Select value some thing like row["table2.CreatedOn"]

Comment: Though you want to select all columns from both the tables, you can select them like this, `table1.*, table2.*, table2.CreatedOn as CreatedOn2`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your approach to creating sql command text in that way is prone to problems and the worst one is the Sql Injection attack, but said that and looking at your actual code the simplest way to reference the second column is following the ADO.NET convention for these cases.

If there are two or more columns with the same name in the table created by your SELECT query then the names of the conflicting columns are changed appending a progressive number to the name. So your second CreatedOn columns becomes CreateOn1. You could refer to this column when you build the AuditLog instance.

```
records.Add(new AuditLog
{
    CreatedOn = row["CreatedOn1"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(row["CreatedOn1"].ToString()) : DateTime.MinValue,
});
```

Still, I think that you need a different approach. One that allows you better control on what you want to return fron your query. Returning all rows from the underlying tables when you need only one column is a very bad practice. Probably a list of columns required could be added to your format string. (and this allows also to append an ALIAS of your choice to the second column CreateOn)